# Problemas en validar campos

Tags: django

Tengo el siguiente problema de validación que me gustaria que me ayudaran ya que soy nuevo en django.

Lo que necesito es hacer una validación para que cuando inserte los datos no se me repitan los datos, especificamente el id_portador y el mes.
Ejemplo: si ya inserte portador: "Gasolina" en el mes: "Enero"
entonces que cuando vuelva a insertar datos y por error intente insertar los mismos datos el sistema de lance un error y no me deje

Comment: Hola Julio, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías [edit] y mostrar el código que has probado, como ejemplo de lo que estás explicando. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y que visites [ask] para aprender a realizar un [example]. Recibirás más respuestas, y de calidad, si la pregunta está correctamente redactada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno encontre que debo poner en el model que crea esta tabla dentro de la funcion meta la propiedad unique_together=['id_portador', 'mes'], asi que cuando intente volver a insertar un portador en ese mes no me dejara hacerlo